# Call a Phone number and pass DTMF using iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, dtmf

How to achieve the below requirement using iOS?

1) Programmatically dial a Phone Number through iOS.

2) Send additional DTMF after the number is called.

I found `tel` URL scheme is available to make a call. Not sure about sending DTMF tones.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html

Answer (score 6):

You can’t send DTMF tones over the Phone app directly with the SDK. However, you can append numbers to the phone number like so:

- Semicolon: wait to dial the next number. The Phone app will show a button.
- Comma: wait 1 second (I think) and then dial the number automatically.

#### Example:

Let's say you want to dial 1-800-555-1212, automatically key in <kbd>2</kbd> after 3 seconds to pick an option from a voice menu, and then allow the user to press a button that will dial <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>. You would pass the following as your phone URL:

```
@"tel:1-800-555-1212,,,2;45"
```

This also works in the Contacts and Phone apps. You can even put in commas and semicolons when editing someone’s phone number by pressing the <kbd>+ * #</kbd> key on the phone keypad.

I don’t know where this is documented. I figured it out by experimentation and by talking to coworkers who are telephony experts.

Answer (score 0):

1) is done by opening an url wil the tel protocol like

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:1-234-567890"]];
```

2) is afaik not possible in the current SDK

Comment: Thanks for your response. Touch Dial Emoji apps supports to send DTMF http://iphoneappsupport.blogspot.com/

Comment: nope. I googled and found this app(Touch Dial Emoji). I have to send DTMF over the call. Dont know how to do. Let me know if you have any idea how Touch Dial Emoji implemented. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to send DTMF over the call from an app.